# VLLM installation failing

Tags: python, numpy, fastapi, large-language-model

I am trying to run Vicuna 7B-16k on my local system. I am following the steps mentioned in this repo: https://github.com/kbressem/LongHealth.git

While trying to run this command: python3 -m fastchat.serve.vllm_worker 
--model-path lmsys/vicuna-7b-v1.5-16k
--controller http://localhost:21001 
--port 31000 
--worker-address http://localhost:31000

I get the error that No Module named 'vllm'. When I try to pip install vllm, I get the error:

```
C:\Users\priya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_bbnsxgu\overlay\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\transformer.py:20: UserWarning: Failed to initialize NumPy: No module named 'numpy' (Triggered internally at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\torch\csrc\utils\tensor_numpy.cpp:84.)
    device: torch.device = torch.device(torch._C._get_default_device()),  # torch.device('cpu'),
  No CUDA runtime is found, using CUDA_HOME='C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.4'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\priya\long heatlh\lh_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
      main()
    File "c:\users\priya\long heatlh\lh_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 263, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "c:\users\priya\long heatlh\lh_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 114, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\priya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_bbnsxgu\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
    File "C:\Users\priya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_bbnsxgu\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\priya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_bbnsxgu\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 446, in <module>
    File "<string>", line 406, in get_vllm_version
  NameError: name 'nvcc_cuda_version' is not defined
```

I have tried re-installing NumPy, but still get the same error. NumPy version= 1.26.4

I have also tried to do this with Cuda 12.1 but still face the same issue.